# Error in M2E Pro invoice/shipment increment ID duplicate key

Tags: magento-1.7, sales, m2e, increment-id

I am using M2E Pro and sometimes Magento shows me an error stating that invoice or shipment is not created.

`Error for invoice creation: Invoice was not created. Reason: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '53000000066' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID'`

`Error for Shipment creation: Shipment was not created. Reason: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '53000000001' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_SHIPMENT_INCREMENT_ID'`

May I please know how can I solve these errors?

Comment: This looks like a server resource error, regardless you should open a ticket with M2E

Comment: This may or may not be an issue with M2E. I've asked them for input.

Answer (score 3):

This error is not related to M2E Pro, but to the state of the data in the database.
It looks like increment ID is not valid, because of some activity.

This issue might appear if you use Fooman's SameOrderInvoiceNumber extension or have made a migration of your site to another hosting recently.

Please check this post about how to fix this issue here:
http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/magento-ecommerce/magento-error-creating-orders-unq_sales_flat_invoice_increment_id